# Why does Google App Engine Standard Edition for Java create a __static__ folder and double the number of files deployed to a project?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am deploying a web application to Google App Engine Standard edition using Java 8.

It is a documentation web site plus servlets that includes a huge amount of static web content (built with Jekyll).

I recently started getting this error trying to deploy the app:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: This deployment has too many files. 
New versions are limited to 10000 files for this app.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
  fieldViolations:
  - description: This deployment has too many files. 
New versions are limited to 10000 files for this app.
    field: version.deployment.files[...]
```

My `src/main/webapp` folder has 5016 files.

But after running:

```
mvn clean install appengine:stage
```

my `target/appengine-staging` folder has 10113 files.

I see that the files are in 2 locations, both

`target/appengine-staging`

and

`target/appengine-staging/__static__`

**Why do they appear twice?**

Is this normal?

Or am I doing something wrong?

How can I avoid this duplication?

Or do I have to limit my files to under 5000?

Thanks for any advice.

Note: The generated app.yaml looks like this:

```
runtime: java8
instance_class: F1
inbound_services:
- warmup
derived_file_type:
- java_precompiled
threadsafe: True
auto_id_policy: default
beta_settings:
  'source_reference': 'https://...'
api_version: 'user_defined'
handlers:
- url: (/.*/)
  static_files: __static__\1index.html
  upload: __NOT_USED__
  require_matching_file: True
  login: optional
  secure: always
- url: (/)
  static_files: __static__\1index.html
  upload: __NOT_USED__
  require_matching_file: True
  login: optional
  secure: always
- url: (/.*)
  static_files: __static__\1
  upload: __NOT_USED__
  require_matching_file: True
  login: optional
  secure: always
- url: /.*
  script: unused
  login: optional
  secure: always

skip_files: app.yaml
```

Comment: As the error says, there is a limit of 10,000 files and actually the files inside `target/appengine-staging` are the ones to be deployed. You can contact GCP support to check if it is possible to increase this limit.